# Scraping table from website (forexfactory.com)

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

need some some help with scraping a simple table from forexfactory.com. The code below works but the formatting is pretty wonky and the columns there seems to be a column that isnt working properly. I know the code I used is pretty novice. Open to improvements.

```
Sub Pulldata2()

 Dim ieObj As InternetExplorer
 Dim appIE As Object
 Dim htmlEle As IHTMLElement
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim strSheet As String
 Dim LastRow As Long
    
 strSheet = Sheet1.Range("A3")
    
       
    Set ieObj = New InternetExplorer
    ieObj.Visible = False
    ieObj.navigate Sheet1.Range("A3").Value
    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
    Sheet2.Activate
    
        
    For Each htmlEle In ieObj.document.getElementsByClassName("calendar__table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")
        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        i = 1 + LastRow
        With ActiveSheet
        
            .Range("A" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(1).textContent
            .Range("B" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(2).textContent
            .Range("C" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(3).textContent
            .Range("D" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(4).textContent
            .Range("E" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(5).textContent
            .Range("F" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(6).textContent
            .Range("G" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(7).textContent
            .Range("H" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(8).textContent
       
          
    End With
    i = i + 1
    On Error Resume Next
Next htmlEle
        


End Sub
```

What is currently happening:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show what an example output row would look like. For example, do you want the Actual, Forecast, Previous values? Knowing what the output should look like is the first step to a good scrape and will help us to help you.

Comment: Hey QHarr! thanks for the reply. I updated the post to show what is happening. Ideally all I want to pull in is the Date, Currency, the report, then Actual, Forecast and Previous. You can see in my code i'm trying to skip columns. Thanks in advance - you previously helped me out before, appreciate it.

Comment: Do you want just the first (latest) date in the table?

Comment: Yeah - i'm not too picky. You are talking about TueApr 6 date right? I would just want it under the Date as a single cell.

Comment: I meant, you want only the data for that date right?

Comment: Oh yeah just for the current date.

Comment: @StephenLong QHarr's code runs well for me. For the error you get, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set) and try the solutions in it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to note is that content is present in view source meaning it can be requested by xmlhttp without resorting to the overhead of a browser.

The next thing to note is that each of the target columns can be targeted by a specific class. In order to start from the correct row, ignoring headers a parent class must also be specified.

As the css selector is long, but not complex, I generate it through a loop.

I use the css selector to return all the td nodes within the target columns. I loop that list using a little math, based on number of columns being retrieved (note I am not retrieving date in this nodeList; I already grab that earlier in script then add it to placeholder first column). This way I re-create the table with the desired columns only.

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WriteTable()
    'tools > references > Microsoft HTML Object Library
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, xhr As Object
    
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    With xhr
        .Open "GET", "https://www.forexfactory.com/", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Dim dateText As String
    
    dateText = html.querySelector(".flexDatePicker").Value
    
    Dim css As String, base As String, classSet()
    
    base = ", .calendar__row > "                 'parent class to prefix each child class
    classSet = Array(".calendar__time", ".calendar__currency", ".calendar__event", _
                     ".calendar__actual", ".calendar__forecast", ".calendar__previous") 'classes to match on
    css = ".calendar__row >  " & Join$(classSet, base) 'final selector
    
    Dim tableCells As Object, r As Long, res As Long, c As Long, results()
    
    Set tableCells = html.querySelectorAll(css)
    r = 1
    
    ReDim results(1 To tableCells.Length / 6, 1 To 7) 'calc size of results array based on 6 columns + 1 for date (previously calculated)
    
    results(1, 1) = dateText
    
    For c = 0 To tableCells.Length - 1
        res = c Mod 6
        results(r, res + 2) = tableCells.Item(c).innerText
        If res = 5 Then r = r + 1                'new row in array
    Next
    
    'array fill down time and populate blank date rows
    For r = UBound(results, 1) To LBound(results, 1) + 1 Step -1
        results(r, 2) = IIf(results(r, 2) = vbNullString, results(r - 1, 2), results(r, 2))
        results(r, 1) = dateText
    Next
    
    Dim headers()
    
    headers = Array("Date", "Time", "Currency", "Event", "Actual", "Forecast", "Previous")
    
    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
    
End Sub
```

---

**Reading:**

1. [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

---

A more traditional approach might look like the following (though a re-factor is needed to reduce the level of nesting):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WriteTable()
    'tools > references > Microsoft HTML Object Library
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, xhr As Object
    
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    With xhr
        .Open "GET", "https://www.forexfactory.com/", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Dim dateText As String
    
    dateText = html.querySelector(".flexDatePicker").Value
    
    Dim table As MSHTML.HTMLTable, r As Long, c As Long, results() As Variant, n As Long
    
    Set table = html.querySelector(".calendar__table")
  
    ReDim results(1 To table.Rows.Length - 4, 1 To 7) 'calc size of results array based on 6 columns + 1 for date (previously calculated)

    results(1, 1) = dateText
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    For r = 4 To table.Rows.Length - 1
        n = 2
        If table.Rows(r).Children.Length = 10 Then
            If table.Rows(r).Children(4).innerText <> vbNullString Then
                i = i + 1
                For c = 1 To table.Rows(r).Children.Length - 1
                    Select Case c
                    Case 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8
                        results(i, n) = table.Rows(r).Children(c).innerText
                        n = n + 1
                    End Select
                Next
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    results = Application.Transpose(results)
    ReDim Preserve results(1 To 7, 1 To i)
    results = Application.Transpose(results)
    
    'array fill down time and populate blank date rows
    For r = UBound(results, 1) To LBound(results, 1) + 1 Step -1
        results(r, 2) = IIf(results(r, 2) = vbNullString, results(r - 1, 2), results(r, 2))
        results(r, 1) = dateText
    Next
    
    Dim headers() As Variant
    
    headers = Array("Date", "Time", "Currency", "Event", "Actual", "Forecast", "Previous")
    
    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi QHarr - I'm getting an error on this line  

dateText = html.querySelector(".flexDatePicker").Value

Comment: Code runs fine for me

Comment: I saved the error picture in the main post. Could it be soemthing in my references. I added the Microsoft HTML Object Library

Comment: When you press debug is the line highlighted in yellow for `dateText = html.querySelector` ?

Comment: You can try replacing with `html.getElementsByClassName("flexdatepicker__date")(0).getElementsByTagName("input").value`