# VBA Excel parsing ForexFactory Calendar - problem with previous question

Tags: excel, vba

With reference to a previous question:
[Scraping table from website (forexfactory.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66962641/scraping-table-from-website-forexfactory-com)

I get the following error ...
Run-time error '91': Object Variable or With block variable not set on both the following lines (first one is from that question's answer and the second one is from comments):

```
'both lines error
dateText = html.querySelector(".flexDatePicker").Value
dateText = html.getElementsByClassName("flexdatepicker__date")(0).getElementsByTagName("input").Value
```

I've read the comments and the references but still can't resolve it. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Probably there is no element with the class `flexDatePicker` or `flexdatepicker__date` on the page, so the calls return `Nothing`.

Comment: Please provide some simplified code and a URL that shows the problem. Also, please show the exact error message that is generated and the line on which the error is generated.

Comment: Error 91 is possibly caused by the statement `dateText = html.querySelector(".flexDatePicker").Value` not being fully qualified. I can not test it if the code you are posting is a fragment like this. I want to copy and paste the code into Excel and run it as is.

Comment: thanks for quick repsonses - all the code is on the post that I refer to; I haven't duplicated it here

Comment: Are you wedded to VBA? This web site seems to be easily scraped using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft `365`.

Comment: Ron - no, but I have never used that in Excel. I will look into that, thanks - if you know of any good articles or have done it on this site please let me know .. at the end of the day I'm trying to get the calendar events from ForexFactory into a worksheet in an automated way

Comment: @garybravo There are a number of examples, both here and elsewhere. Suggest you start by pasting a url into the `Get Data from Web` dialog of Excel, but also read about PQ.

Comment: I've had a play with Power Query and the ForexFactory calendar is not easy for it. One column that is very important to me is the Impact column and they use a different icon in there for high/medium/low and it doesnt seem to be able to show the icon name at all

Comment: @garybravo You did ***NOT*** show that column in your `what I want` example in your other question.  If you cannot figure out how to fix the code you are using, consider posting a question that properly lays out what you are trying to do.  [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might be helpful.